# Java - separate numbers from a string

Tags: java

I have a string that contains a few numbers (usually a date) and separators. The separators can either be "," or "." - or example 01.05,2000.5000

....now I need to separate those numbers and put into an array but I'm not sure how to do that (the separating part). Also, I need to check that the string is valid - it cannot be 01.,05.

I'm not asking for anyone to solve the thing for me (but if someone wants I appreciated it), just point me in the right direction :)

Comment: `String#split(...)` allows for regular expressions to be used as the delimiter. I'd experiment with that. All you need is something very simple.

Comment: Is your string contains "," and '.' both in a single string ?

Comment: @JDeveloper I would say yes since his example has both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of doing it with [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class, just iterate the tokens and if the obtained token is empty then you have a invalid String, also, convert the tokens to integers by the [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) method to check if they are valid integer numbers:

```
import java.util.*;
public class t {
    public static void main(String... args)  { 
        String line = "01.05,2000.5000";
        StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(line, ",.");
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String s = strTok.nextToken();
            if (s.length() == 0) { 
                // Found a repeated separator, String is not valid, do something about it
            } 
            try { 
                int value = Integer.parseInt(s, 10);
                values.add(value);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
                // Number not valid, do something about it or continue the parsing 
            }
        }

        // At the end, get an array from the ArrayList
        Integer[] arrayOfValues = values.toArray(new Integer[values.size()]);

        for (Integer i : arrayOfValues) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through an [`String#split(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) generated array and check each value to make sure your source `String` is "valid".

In:

```
String src = "01.05,2000.5000";
String[] numbers = src.split("[.,]");
```

`numbers` here will be an array of `Strings`, like `{"01", "05", "2000", "5000"}`. Each value is a number.

Now iterate over `numbers`. If you find a index that is not a number (it's a number when `numbers[i].matches("\\d+")` is `true`), then your `src` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

To validate:

```
if (input.matches("^(?!.*[.,]{2})[\\d.,]+))
```

This regex checks that:

- dot and comma are never adjacent
- input is comprised only of digits, dots and commas

---

To split:

```
String[] numbers = input.split("[.,]");
```

Comment: Thanks . Its working fine. Could you please help me to how to learn regexp easily.

Comment: sir, shouldn't `numbers` be an Array as split function returns an Array ?

Comment: @JDeveloper The best way to learn regex is to practice practice practice. Try answering regex questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to group and match the input

```
    String s = "01.05,2000.5000";       
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})[.,](\\d{2})[.,](\\d{4})[.,](\\d{4})");      
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

    if(m.matches()) {
        String[] matches = { m.group(1),m.group(2), m.group(3),m.group(4) };
        for(String match : matches) {
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Mismatch");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would use guava String splitter for that. It is much more reliable, predictable and flexible than `String#split`. You can tell it exactly what to expect, what to omit, and so on.

For an example usage, and a small rant on how stupid javas `split` sometimes behaves, have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
String str = "01.05,2000.5000";
str = str.replace(".",",");
int number = StringUtils.countMatches(str, ",");
String[] arrayStr = new String[number+1];
arrayStr = str.split(",");
```

`StringUtils` is from `Apache Commons` >> http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate the string, use split(), the argument of the method is the delimiter

array = string.split("separator");

Comment: `split()` requires the use of regular expressions, which is why I deleted my answer

Comment: First, have to check that the string is valid, then can use the split method, I think